# How can multi-touch be used in uiautomator?

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-uiautomator

I haven't found any way to automate multi-touch movements in uiautomator tests

Given it's framework of com.android.uiautomator.* classes, how can I automate multi-touch movements?

Comment: It looks like you may be able to use a combination of InputManager.getInstance().injectInputEvent() and MotionEvent.obtain() to create this kind of infrastructure. I haven't found any way to automatically do it, so i'm accepting the below answer.

Comment: please read the updated document Since Android API Level 18:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiObject.html
I think that the performMultiPointerGesture function should be your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 01 March 2017
When I first answered this question the current documentation for Android-17 e.g. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiObject.html did not seem to provide any way to provide multi-touch or other complex gestures such as pinch & zoom.

However as @Project pointed out, multitouch gestures are now supported. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiObject#performmultipointergesture

I have not tested this capability, at this stage.

Comment: I'll +1 your response, but want to wait a little longer before accepting it :)

Comment: Wait as long as you need to :) Let's hope Google prove us both wrong by providing the functionality!

Comment: This answer is no longer correct.  Suggest updating, since it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

In android API level 18 android  UiObject has provide api for such multipoint gesture. [check here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiObject.html#pinchIn%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pinchOut / pinchIn methods to do Zoom out and Zoom in. Or use Multitouch gestures as JulianHarty pointed out if you want more fine-grained control.

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        device.findObject(uiSelector).pinchOut(percent, steps);
```